# How to convert ODataEnumValue into its CLR enum type?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

While traversing the expression tree from a `FilterQueryOption`, I have an instance of a `ODataEnumValue`. I'm wondering how to convert that into the corresponding CLR enum type value in generic way (i.e. without having to look-up the actual CLR type myself).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The enum type can be retrieved by getting the `ClrTypeAnnotation` of the `TypeReference` as follows. First get the model from the `FilterQueryOption` instance:

```
IEdmModel _model = filterQueryOption.Context.Model;
```

Then, later when parsing its `FilterClause`, for example for a `ConstantNode`:

```
    private object GetClrValue(ConstantNode constantNode)
    {
        ODataEnumValue enumValue;
        ...
        else if ((enumValue = constantNode.Value as ODataEnumValue) != null)
        {
            var annotation = _model.GetAnnotationValue<ClrTypeAnnotation>(constantNode.TypeReference.Definition);
            Type enumType = annotation.ClrType;
            parameterValue = Enum.Parse(enumType, enumValue.Value);
        }
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can refer to [ODataEnumDeserializer](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/blob/master/OData/src/System.Web.OData/OData/Formatter/Deserialization/ODataEnumDeserializer.cs)'s ReadInline method, which convert ODataEnumvalue to CLR enum type if it is in EdmModel.

Comment: I don't have a deserialization context. I'm trying to retrieve the CLR enum type from a `FilterQueryOption` instance that is created using `ODataQueryOptions` in a `ODataController`.